# Cant we use simple class object as key in std::map?

Tags: stdmap

```
class abc
{
};

int main()
{
    std::map<abc, int> m;
    abc ob, ob1;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(ob, 1));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(ob1, 2));
}
```

Error coming is:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_function.h:237:22: note:   ‘const abc’ is not derived from ‘const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’

Does any addition function need be added in class so that it can be made hashable?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Since std::map sorts when entering a new key in map, so if key is a class object, we must overload class's "<" operator, then it would work fine.

```
class abc
{
        public:
        bool operator< (const abc& userObj) const
        {
                return true;
        }
};

int main()
{
        std::map<abc, int> m;
        abc ob;
        abc ob1;
        m.insert(std::make_pair(ob, 1));
        m.insert(std::make_pair(ob1, 2));
}
```